# Route [auth.login] not defined. laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I'm getting this error out of a sudden after everything was working fine.  [ra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKSdC.jpg)

Comment: Can't say anything with that image. Do you see auth.login in php artisan route: list ?

Comment: @MHIdea the picture shows the `Auth::routes()` line in web.php

Comment: pls do php artisan route:list. is it there?? it must be login not auth.login

Comment: @WiGeeky , yes It's there, it might not be cached. And also check above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Although Auth::routes() is included, as a general rule, you can always check list of routes with names and middlewares by:

```sh
php artisan route:list
```

You'll probably see **login** not **auth.login**. auth.login is a view not route. If you can't find login you probably need to cache routes by:

```sh
php artisan route:cache
```